# Range/Segment Tree Ruby

Tags: ruby, segment-tree, range-tree

I am looking for a range or segment tree implementation in Ruby. I could not find any sample or gem available.

Does anyone have a sample code ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This [Github repo](https://github.com/misshie/interval-tree) is...um...[the fourth hit down on Google for 'ruby interval tree'](http://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&cp=18&gs_id=1&xhr=t&q=ruby%20interval%20tree&pf=p&sclient=psy&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=ruby%20interval%20tree&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=9588886a00bb2ae1&biw=1440&bih=802&ion=1).

Answer (score 1):

There looks to be one called `interval-tree`, repo is here, https://github.com/gam3/interval-tree and here https://github.com/misshie/interval-tree. It seems like it is the later who made the thing, but the gem on rubygems points to the first. Very strange.

The documentation is wrong on the repo and everywhere else. To use it, use either `IntervalTree::InclusiveTree.new` or `IntervalTree::ExclusiveTree.new`. This is not documented anywhere which is strange. Also, equally strange, it is not possible to add issues to the github repo to fix this. I am considering forking and making a new version which can be maintained by the community.

Anyways, here is how you use it:

```
require "interval-tree"

itv = [(0...3), (1...4), (3...5),]
t = IntervalTree::Tree.new(itv)
p t.search(2) => [0...3, 1...4]
p t.search(1...3) => [0...3, 1...4, 3...5]
```

As you see, also the require statement is wrongly documented in the repo. What a mess.